# AWS amplify - Can't synchronize via DataStore if I use an API Key; but Cognito User Pools work

Tags: aws-amplify

I've setup an amplify project for react.js, which should allow authorized and unauthorized access to my application.
Therefore, I've configured two authentication methods: Cognito User Pools and API key. The first one is my default.
My application runs fine, if I sign in via the Cognito User Pool. All data is beeing synchronized via the DataStore.
But if I switch to the API Key as unauthenticated user, I only get unauthorized errors under the hood. E.g. for one of my custom types:

```
errorType: "Unauthorized"
message: "Not Authorized to access onCreateMyCustomType on type Subscription"
```

The API key is sent correctly as "x-api-key".

If I manually query the Graph-API (e.g. via the amplify.js-API in my application or the third party tool GraphiQL), I can get the results. Just the synchronization isn't working as it does for authenticated users.

In my schema, I control the access via @auth. E.g.:

```
@auth(rules: [
    # Owner access
    { allow: owner },

    # System access
    { allow: private, provider: iam },

    # Admin access
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },

    # Default user access
    { allow: groups, groups: ["User"], operations: [read] },

    # Everyone
    { allow: public, operations: [read] }
  ])
```

I'm switching the authentication method via:

```
Amplify.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  aws_appsync_authenticationType: isAuthenticated ? 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS' : 'API_KEY',
});
```

Comment: where are these annotations placed inside what files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue.
There wasn't a public access defined for some custom types, so the whole synchronization failed. After uncommenting these in my scheme and pushing the changes, all data could be synchronized. A better approach could be selective sync to disable the synchronization for the affected types, if the user isn't signed in. But I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Did you have to define public access (`@auth`) for the custom types, even if those did not have the `@model` directive?

Update: I get `Types annotated with @auth must also be annotated with @model.`

Comment: yep. all are annotated with @model

Comment: your answer given says to uncomment "these" in your "scheme".
could you please give a more detailed solution?

Answer (score -1):

In aws-exports.js try changing
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AWS_IAM",
to whatever authentication type you are using like. For example,
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js/

If this works you can make it permanent by running

> amplify update api

then select graphql and update authorization modes.

Otherwise add additional authorization types in the AppSync schema:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/